# Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, to be a valid callback

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I am using wordpress plugin Ultimate Membership Pro. I have a small warning in my code. I can't figure out what the issue is.

I tried checking php manual and also doing research on this topic but can't solve it. Anyone have an idea how to solve it? Just need a hint.

**Php Code:**

Original Code:

```
if (!empty($data->history)){
        //print the history
        $dat = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $data->history);
        $dat = unserialize($dat);       
        if (isset($dat) && is_array($dat)){
            foreach ($dat as $k=>$transaction_history_arr){
                if (is_string($transaction_history_arr)){
                    //is json
                    $json = stripslashes($transaction_history_arr);
                    if ($k){
                        echo '<h4>' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $k) .'</h4>';
                    }
                    $arr = (array)json_decode($json, true);
                    foreach ($arr as $key=>$value){
                        echo $key.': '.$value.'<br/>';
                    }
                } else {    
                    //is an array
                    if ($k>0){ 
                        echo '<h4>' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $k) .'</h4>';
                    }
                    foreach ($transaction_history_arr as $key=>$value){
                        echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br/>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

> Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead in
>   /var/www/html/stock-market/wp-content/plugins/indeed-membership-pro/admin/includes/tabs/list_payments.php
>   on line 44

**Updated with preg_replace_callback:**

```
if (!empty($data->history)){
        //print the history
        print_r($data->history);
        $dat = preg_replace_callback('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $data->history);
        $dat = unserialize($dat);
```

For updated Output something like this:

> Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2,
>   ''s:'.strlen('$2').':"$2";'', to be a valid callback in
>   /var/www/html/stock-market/wp-content/plugins/indeed-membership-pro/admin/includes/tabs/list_payments.php
>   on line 44 2017-06-17 08:44:49

```
  ihc_payment_type : paypal  
   details : ss  
   uid : 1 
   level : 2 
   order_id : 21
   amount : 100.00
   currency : USD  
   txn_id : 1_21_1497689089 
   message : success
```

my array is **$data->history** :

> a:1:{i:1497689089;a:9:{s:16:"ihc_payment_type";s:6:"paypal";s:7:"details";s:2:"ss";s:3:"uid";s:1:"1";s:5:"level";s:1:"2";s:8:"order_id";s:2:"21";s:6:"amount";s:6:"100.00";s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:6:"txn_id";s:15:"1_21_1497689089";s:7:"message";s:7:"success";}}

**Warning:**

```
 Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, ''s:'.strlen('$2').':"$2";'', to be a valid callback in /var/www/html/stock-market/wp-content/plugins/indeed-membership-pro/admin/includes/tabs/list_payments.php on line 47
```

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward. I think you just want `preg_replace` instead.

Comment: @smarx i changed it `preg_replace` to `preg_replace_callback` and that give me warning my php does not support `preg_replace` php 7.x

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php, `preg_replace` should be supported in PHP 7. What's the exact error message?

Comment: @smarx Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/html/stock-market/wp-content/plugins/indeed-membership-pro/admin/includes/tabs/list_payments.php on line 44

Comment: You cannot use a plain text string with variables in it, it needs to be a callable (function), please check the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_replace\_callback(): Requires argument 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457839/preg-replace-callback-requires-argument-2)

Comment: Oh, delete the `e` at the end of your search pattern.

Comment: Unless you need it? (If that's the case, you do want `preg_replace_callback`, but you need to pass in an actual function.)

Comment: It might help if you explained what you're trying to do. (E.g. what should the output be?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm right about what you're trying to do, this might be what you're looking for:

```
$text = 'a:1:{i:1497689089;a:9:{s:16:"ihc_payment_type";s:6:"paypal";s:7:"details";s:2:"ss";s:3:"uid";s:1:"1";s:5:"level";s:1:"2";s:8:"order_id";s:2:"21";s:6:"amount";s:6:"100.00";s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:6:"txn_id";s:15:"1_21_1497689089";s:7:"message";s:7:"success";}}';

$dat = preg_replace_callback('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!',
    function ($match) {
        return 's:'.strlen($match[2]).':"'.$match[2].'";';
    },
    $text);
```

Note that I've dropped the `e` modifier from the search pattern and then passed in a function as the second parameter. This function takes a match and returns the replacement you want.

(Also note that for the given input, this replacement doesn't change anything.)

Comment: Thanks! Work like charm :)